# My iOs app is rejected due to 2.2: Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova

I am so worried about my new issue with submitting my app to itune store. This gives me error in resolution center like:

----- 2.2 -----

We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, the app launches to a blank screen.

For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:

- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

What is the issue with my app this is second time when my app is rejected?

Please guide me whats the mistake?

Thanks in Advance.

Vijay

Comment: Have you tested your app on an iPad running iOS 8?

Comment: no, from where I will test it. I havent ipad with ios 8 os. is any solution from which I can remove this version from my app?

Comment: Well, you can try testing it on the iPad simulator, but there can be differences between the simulator and a real device.  Apps must run on both iPhone and iPad devices to be accepted into the app store

Comment: But I need this app only running inside iphone any idea how to run any app for specific device?

Comment: Refer to App Store Policy 2.10 - "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution" http://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: have you ipad ios8 can you please test http://build.phonegap.com/apps/1066313/install?

Comment: It fails to install on my ipad

Comment: can you please send me your udid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62103/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user1903724).